# How to find specific item in Json Array and manipulate in c#

Tags: c#, json

I have a complex json file where I can have multiple type of resources, type could be repeating as well. Given this I have two questions, I tried to search on net but didn't find any clue.

1. How I can find specific type say `type3` resource object, it could return multiple results
2. Once I find specific resource, I want to add one more property and save it back as json

   ```
   { 
   "resources": [{
       "type": "type1",
       "name": "dummy1",
       "properties": {
           "p1": "v1"
       }
   }, {
       "type": "type2",
       "name": "dummy2",
       "properties": {
           "p1": "v1",
           "p2": {
               "k1": "v1"
           }
       }
   }, {
       "type": "type3",
       "name": "dummy3",
       "properties": {
           "p1": {
               "k1": "v1"
           },
           "p2": {
               "k1": "v1",
               "k2": "v2"
           }
       }
   }, {
       "type": "type3",
       "name": "dummy4",
       "properties": {
           "p1": {
               "k1": "v1"
           },
           "p2": {
               "k1": "v1",
               "k2": "v2"
           }
       }
       }]
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, get a JSON library. I recommend `Newtonsoft.Json` (install as a `NuGet` package).

I'm using a File api, but it's pretty easy to construct a `JObject` in another way. The `ToString` call returns the JSON string again. I'm also using `Linq` to find the array elements where the type is type3.

```
JObject jObject = JObject.Load(
    new JsonTextReader(File.OpenText("Data.json")));
JArray resources = (JArray)jObject["resources"];
foreach (var type3Resource in resources
    .Where(obj => obj["type"].Value<string>() == "type3"))
{
    type3Resource["SpecialValue"] = 3;
}

File.WriteAllText("Data2.json", 
    jObject.ToString(Formatting.Indented));
```